# call shopify api Creating a checkout response variantid is invalid

Tags: api, shopify, checkout

i call api Creating a checkout

the variant_id is 38894644552 is correct ,but this api response

```
variantid is is invalid
```

1. get my shop variant id

   get https://suisui.myshopify.com/admin/products/9981337608/variants.json 
   Response: { "variants": [ { "id": 38894644552, "product_id": 9981337608,...
2. Creating a checkout with variant id

   POST /admin/checkouts.json HTTP/1.1
   Host: suisui.myshopify.com
   X-Shopify-Access-Token: xxx
   Content-Type: application/json

   { "checkout": { "lineitems": [ { "variantid": 38894644552, "quantity": 3 }

   Response:

   { "errors": { "lineitems": { "0": { "variantid": [ { "code": "invalid", "message": "is invalid", "options": {} }

what's wrong with variantid 38894644552 ?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Your app must be a sales channel for this api to work,

In Shopify Partners got to App Setup and it should look like this:
[image]

You will need to remove all existing installations to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The variant has to be for a product published to the checkout

e.g. After you've installed your checkout API app

- go to products and locate the Sales Channels box.
- Click Manage
- Click your checkout channel
- Click Done
- click Save

Comment: thank you, i add my product to sales channel ,it's resolved.

Comment: The only checkbox in Manage, "Online store", is checked, but I still get the "is invalid" response.