# Invalid Varient ID Shopify (Admin Rest Api)

Tags: node.js, shopify, checkout

I am trying to create a checkout via Shopify admin rest API and in response, I am getting a validation error which looks like this.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "line_items": {
            "0": {
                "variant_id": [
                    {
                        "code": "invalid",
                        "message": "is invalid",
                        "options": {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Request[POST]:

URL: https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/checkouts.json

```
{
  "checkout": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": "15465470460017",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I verified the varient_id by looking into the cart JSON on the link "https://mystore.myshopify.com/cart.json".
I also followed the documentation given on Shopify. If I create empty checkout without varient_id then it works otherwise it returns the invalid variant id error.

I tried this request on PostMan. For updated and others it is working fine but for checkout create I couldn't find the point where I am going wrong.

Comment: As mentioned in [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/sales_channels/checkout#create) , invalid error mayalso occur if the product is not published to your sales channel. Check that too to be sure.

Comment: The only sales channel that appears in `product page > Product availability > Manage` is "Online store" and it is checked, but I'm getting the response shown in the question.

Comment: is there anyone know the solution for above issue?

Comment: Your app must be a sales channel, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214680/265419